# How can I insert ntext with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, pdf, ef-database-first, cyrillic

I need execute this type of command `Insert table(column) values (N'текст') with Entity Framework

Here my code

```
 public ActionResult PDFGeneration(string format)
 {
        var myFont = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Font/"), "font.ttf");
        Rectangle pgeSize = new Rectangle(595, 792);

        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 0f);
        PdfWriter pdfwriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);

        pdfDoc.Open();

        BaseFont bfR = BaseFont.CreateFont(myFont ,BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

        BaseColor clrBlack = new BaseColor(0, 0, 0);
        Font fntHead = new Font(bfR, 12, Font.NORMAL, clrBlack);

        //pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Літера ї є я ь", fntHead));


        using (MedicalDictionaryEntities mde = new MedicalDictionaryEntities())
        {

            mde.Database.Connection.Open();
            var listTUa = from x in mde.TranslationUA select x;
            foreach (TranslationUA tua in listTUa)
            {
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                builder.Append(tua.Word).Append(" - ");

                foreach(TranslationEN ten in tua.TranslationEN)
                {
                    builder.Append(ten.Word).Append(", ");
                }

                pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph(builder.ToString(),fntHead));
            }
        }

        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Generated.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();

        return View("Index");
    }
```

I works but I am getting `???????` instead of the Cyrillic letters.

I added these columns to entity model, but it didn't help

```
    [MaxLength]
    [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
    public string Word { get; set; }
```

I tried to execute `Insert table(column) values (N'текст')` in SQL Server and it worked.

So my question is: how can I execute this type of command using code and EF?

Comment: Do you use entity framework `Code-First` or you are using an `edmx`?

Comment: I posted an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `Database-First` or `Model-First`, you should edit your `edmx`. Setting those attributes on model will not work for you.

Open your edmx in designer and then select your field, in properties of the field, Set `Max Length` to `Max` and `Unicode` to `true`.

You can also remove that entity from your edmx and then right click and select `Update Model from Database ...` and add the entity again, this way if the field is `ntext` in database, settings will be done for the field in edmx.

Comment: Thank you, replacing entity helped.